# a sql query to compare results of following queries

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT pd_end_dt,SUM(nrx_cnt) Total_Count
FROM wkly_lnd.lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
WHERE pd_end_dt >= '01-Sep-08' AND pd_end_dt < '30-Sep-08'
GROUP BY pd_end_dt

SELECT pd_end_dt,SUM(nrx_cnt) Total_Count
FROM wkly_lnd.lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
WHERE pd_end_dt >= '01-Sep-07' AND pd_end_dt < '30-Sep-07'
GROUP BY pd_end_dt
```

the result set on running each query will be like

```
09/28/2007 00:00:00 702,457.36
09/21/2007 00:00:00 703,604.59
09/07/2007 00:00:00 636,619.92
09/14/2007 00:00:00 698,082.03
```

similarly for previous year

I need to calculate the difference of units sold as compared to last year and also to add one column which will find percentage change

Comment: I can not get the question? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Yes, what exactly do you mean by "compare"?

Comment: What does 'compare' mean? Is it any difference? Is is the delta between Total counts? You should provide an example of what you want.

Comment: the result set on running each query will be like

09/28/2007 00:00:00 702,457.36
09/21/2007 00:00:00 703,604.59
09/07/2007 00:00:00 636,619.92
09/14/2007 00:00:00 698,082.03

similarly for previous year
I need to calculate the difference of units sold as compared to last year and also to add one column which will find percentage change

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things unsaid. I hope you receive clearer requirements in your daily work ...
Anyway, here is a simulation of your situation. It's based on the assumption that the days with data (one per week) are the same in 2007 as in 2008:

```
SQL> create table lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary (pd_end_dt,nrx_cnt)
  2  as
  3  select date '2008-09-07', 100000 from dual union all
  4  select date '2008-09-07', 536619.92 from dual union all
  5  select date '2008-09-14', 698082.03 from dual union all
  6  select date '2008-09-21', 403604.59 from dual union all
  7  select date '2008-09-21', 200000 from dual union all
  8  select date '2008-09-21', 100000 from dual union all
  9  select date '2008-09-28', 702457.36 from dual union all
 10  select date '2007-09-07', 400000 from dual union all
 11  select date '2007-09-14', 450000 from dual union all
 12  select date '2007-09-21', 500000 from dual union all
 13  select date '2007-09-28', 550000 from dual union all
 14  select date '2007-09-28', 100000 from dual
 15  /

Tabel is aangemaakt.
```

And your original queries, slightly modified.

```
SQL> SELECT pd_end_dt
  2       , SUM(nrx_cnt) Total_Count
  3    FROM lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
  4   WHERE pd_end_dt >= date '2008-09-01'
  5     AND pd_end_dt <  date '2008-09-30'
  6   GROUP BY pd_end_dt
  7  /

PD_END_DT           TOTAL_COUNT
------------------- -----------
07-09-2008 00:00:00   636619,92
14-09-2008 00:00:00   698082,03
21-09-2008 00:00:00   703604,59
28-09-2008 00:00:00   702457,36

4 rijen zijn geselecteerd.

SQL> SELECT pd_end_dt
  2       , SUM(nrx_cnt) Total_Count
  3    FROM lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
  4   WHERE pd_end_dt >= date '2007-09-01'
  5     AND pd_end_dt <  date '2007-09-30'
  6   GROUP BY pd_end_dt
  7  /

PD_END_DT           TOTAL_COUNT
------------------- -----------
07-09-2007 00:00:00      400000
14-09-2007 00:00:00      450000
21-09-2007 00:00:00      500000
28-09-2007 00:00:00      650000

4 rijen zijn geselecteerd.
```

And the query with which you can compare the 2007 and 2008 data:

```
SQL> select to_char(pd_end_dt,'dd-mm') day_and_month
  2       , sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2007-01-01' then nrx_cnt end) sum2007
  3       , sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2008-01-01' then nrx_cnt end) sum2008
  4       , sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2008-01-01' then nrx_cnt end)
  5         - sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2007-01-01' then nrx_cnt end) difference
  6       , (  sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2008-01-01' then nrx_cnt end)
  7          - sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2007-01-01' then nrx_cnt end)
  8         ) / sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2008-01-01' then nrx_cnt end) * 100 percentage_difference
  9    from lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
 10   where (  (   pd_end_dt >= date '2007-09-01'
 11            and pd_end_dt <  date '2007-09-30'
 12            )
 13         or (   pd_end_dt >= date '2008-09-07'
 14            and pd_end_dt <  date '2008-09-30'
 15            )
 16         )
 17   group by to_char(pd_end_dt,'dd-mm')
 18  /

DAY_A    SUM2007    SUM2008 DIFFERENCE PERCENTAGE_DIFFERENCE
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
07-09     400000  636619,92  236619,92            37,1681615
14-09     450000  698082,03  248082,03            35,5376617
21-09     500000  703604,59  203604,59            28,9373595
28-09     650000  702457,36   52457,36            7,46769313

4 rijen zijn geselecteerd.
```

Although rather verbose, I think it speaks for itself.
You may like the following rewrite, since it doesn't repeat the aggregate functions as much as in the query above:

```
SQL> select day_and_month
  2       , sum2007
  3       , sum2008
  4       , sum2008-sum2007 difference
  5       , 100*(sum2008-sum2007)/sum2008 percentage_difference
  6    from ( select to_char(pd_end_dt,'dd-mm') day_and_month
  7                , sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2007-01-01' then nrx_cnt end) sum2007
  8                , sum(case trunc(pd_end_dt,'yyyy') when date '2008-01-01' then nrx_cnt end) sum2008
  9             from lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
 10            where (   pd_end_dt >= date '2007-09-01'
 11                  and pd_end_dt <  date '2007-09-30'
 12                  )
 13               or (   pd_end_dt >= date '2008-09-07'
 14                  and pd_end_dt <  date '2008-09-30'
 15                  )
 16            group by to_char(pd_end_dt,'dd-mm')
 17         )
 18  /

DAY_A    SUM2007    SUM2008 DIFFERENCE PERCENTAGE_DIFFERENCE
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
07-09     400000  636619,92  236619,92            37,1681615
14-09     450000  698082,03  248082,03            35,5376617
21-09     500000  703604,59  203604,59            28,9373595
28-09     650000  702457,36   52457,36            7,46769313

4 rijen zijn geselecteerd.
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: DAY_AND_MONTH SUM2007 SUM2008 DIFFERENCE PERCENTAGE_DIFFEREN
14-sep         698,082.03   
19-sep           706,719.21  
07-sep         636,619.92   
21-sep         703,604.59   
28-sep         702,457.36   
26-sep                    731,784.51  
12-sep                    711,813.59

I got the above result running the same query 
It is due to the following  reason

1. We are getting data at the end of week.
   Like the week end date for 08 year for september month are
   05,12,19,26
   and for 07 are
   07,14,21,28
 2. Please let me know how to compare data week wise

Comment: Then change the group by clause and the corresponding expression in the select list to use the format mask 'iw' instead of 'dd-mm'.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare the results of the query year-on-year (ie for each day with the day of the preceeding year), you can group by the day of the year `to_char('dd-mon')`:

```
SQL> WITH lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary AS (
  2  SELECT DATE '2007-09-28' pd_end_dt, 702457.36 nrx_cnt FROM dual
  3  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2007-09-21', 703604.59 FROM dual
  4  --
  5  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2008-09-28' pd_end_dt, 702557.36 nrx_cnt FROM dual
  6  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2008-09-21', 703404.59 FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT to_char(pd_end_dt, 'dd-mon') pd_end_dt,
  9         SUM(CASE
 10                WHEN to_char(pd_end_dt, 'yyyy') = '2007' THEN
 11                 nrx_cnt
 12             END) Total_2007,
 13         SUM(CASE
 14                WHEN to_char(pd_end_dt, 'yyyy') = '2008' THEN
 15                 nrx_cnt
 16             END) Total_2008,
 17         SUM(CASE
 18                WHEN to_char(pd_end_dt, 'yyyy') = '2008' THEN
 19                 nrx_cnt
 20                ELSE
 21                 -nrx_cnt
 22             END) delta
 23    FROM lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
 24   WHERE ((pd_end_dt >= DATE '2007-09-01' AND pd_end_dt < DATE '2007-09-30') OR
 25         (pd_end_dt >= DATE '2008-09-01' AND pd_end_dt < DATE '2008-09-30'))
 26   GROUP BY to_char(pd_end_dt, 'dd-mon');

PD_END_DT    TOTAL_2007 TOTAL_2008      DELTA
------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
28-sep        702457,36  702557,36        100
21-sep        703604,59  703404,59       -200
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you look at the analytic functions provided with Oracle? I am assuming you are using Oracle as you have tagged your question with the Oracle tag.  You can refer to http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/LagLeadAnalyticFunctions.php.

I am simplifying your data set to look like this

```
09/08/2007 100
09/08/2008 200
09/09/2007 350
09/09/2008 400
09/10/2007 150
09/10/2008 175
```

These are your total counts on the 8,9 and 10th of September in the years 2007 and 2008

You can use the following query:

Assuming table to be `T(end_date,cnt)` (your names are too long! sorry )

```
Select end_date, cnt,
       LAG(cnt,1,0) over (order by 
to_number(to_char(end_dt,'dd')),to_number(to_char(end_dt,'mm'))) cntPrev,
       cnt - LAG(cnt,1,0) over (order by 
to_number(to_char(end_dt,'dd')),to_number(to_char(end_dt,'mm'))) cntDiff
from T
```

In simpler terms(this will not work if you copy, paste).

```
Let X=LAG(cnt,1,0) over (order by 
to_number(to_char(end_dt,'dd')),to_number(to_char(end_dt,'mm')))
```

Your query is

```
Select end_date, cnt, X cntPrev, cnt-X cntDiff
from T;
```

Comment: I dont have your tables. I have tested on the sample DB i have. Why dont you look at the link in my reply? It works.

Comment: I'm not the original poster. I did create a table T with your data and the SQL you proposed contains syntax errors. When I correct the syntax, I wonder how the results are going to help the original poster. If you say you have tested, then you have tested something else.

Comment: Can you point out the syntax errors? Since you have raised a question as to if i have tested: Here is the query (I am pasting from my sql client)
Select hiredate, sal,
       LAG(sal,1,0) over (order by to_number(to_char(hiredate,'dd')),to_number(to_char(hiredate,'mm'))) cntPrev,
       sal - LAG(sal,1,0) over (order by to_number(to_char(hiredate,'dd')),to_number(to_char(hiredate,'mm'))) cntDiff
from emp

If you are an oracle user, you must be familiar with the emp table of the scott schema.

Comment: You use end_date as a column_name, but in your analytic functions they are called end_dt...