# need sql query to create join on the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary`
and 
col`umns pd_end_dt, nrx_cnt`
containing data

```
PD_END_DT    NRX_CNT
12/26/08    1,178.75
12/19/08    2,027.12
12/12/08    1,907.08
12/05/08    2,092.90
11/28/08    1,236.44
11/21/08    1,857.82
11/14/08    1,817.55
11/07/08    1,800.54
10/31/08    1,985.13

i need to put a join on same table lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
and compare data of PD_END_DT,NRX_CNT weekly    
so dat i can get difference of NRX_CNT as zero
```

Final table will contain following columns

```
PD_END_DT NRX_CNT DELTA
```

---

snapshot of the table is

```
   MKT_ID   PROD_GRP_NBR    CHNL_CD PERIOD_FILE_TYPE    PD_END_DT   NRX_CNT NRX_QTY
    02601   00000020             1  W   10/12/07    2,041.64    9,706.23
    02601   00000020             1  W   10/05/07    2,122.89    10,593.91
    02601   00000020             1  W   09/28/07    2,072.10    10,247.32
    02601   00000020             1  W   09/21/07    2,070.78    10,042.91
    02601   00000020             1  W   09/14/07    2,120.01    10,493.93
    02601       00000020             1  W   09/07/07    1,828.18    8,867.92
    02601   00000020             1  W   08/31/07    2,294.99    11,115.15
    02601   00000020             1  W   08/24/07    2,133.24    10,434.83
    02601     00000020           1  W   08/17/07    2,186.42    10,739.04
```

CHNL_CD VARIES AS 1 OR 2
PROD_GRP_NBR      20-200
PERIOD_FILE_TYPE IS    W

.........This is just first step to get to the final result............

Comment: I don't really understand your question, I'm afraid. What do you want to compare NRX_CNT to? To compare it to itself doesn't make sense to me as you only have one value per date as it seems. 
To compare all the values week by week you would need a pivoted query, with a column per PD_END_DT. Can you please explain the issue a bit further?

Comment: This question is very related to your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326594/a-sql-query-to-compare-results-of-follwing-queries

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare the `NRX_CNT` column to the preceeding week, you can use an analytic function, it will be faster and clearer than a self-join:

```
SQL>  SELECT pd_end_dt, nrx_cnt,
  2         nrx_cnt - lag(nrx_cnt) over (ORDER BY pd_end_dt) delta
  3    FROM lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary
  4  ORDER BY pd_end_dt;

PD_END_DT      NRX_CNT      DELTA
----------- ---------- ----------
31/10/2008     1985,13 
07/11/2008     1800,54    -184,59
14/11/2008     1817,55      17,01
21/11/2008     1857,82      40,27
28/11/2008     1236,44    -621,38
05/12/2008      2092,9     856,46
12/12/2008     1907,08    -185,82
19/12/2008     2027,12     120,04
26/12/2008     1178,75    -848,37
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find any combination of weeks that have the same NRX_CNT (difference = 0), I would go with something similar to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary as t1
INNER JOIN lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary as t2 on t1.nrx_cnt = t2.nrx_cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Which db type you are using? SQL Server 2005?

select A.PD_END_DT as 'LAST_PD_END_DT', A.NRX_CNT - B.NRX_CNT as 'DELTA'
from lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary as A 
    inner join lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary as B
on A.PD_END_DT =dateadd(d, 7, B.PD_END_DT)

Comment: considering the tag he uses Oracle

Answer (score 0):

what I'm missing here is a citeriea to join the table whith itself.
Anyhow - if there is no criteria you will get 
for every PD_END_DT a set of records for every record in that table which shows the difference
The query looks like this:
SELECT A.PD_END_DT, A.NRX_CNT, A.NRX_CNT - B.NRX_CNT as DELTA
FROM lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary A, lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary B

I you would have a "joinable field" it would look like
SELECT A.PD_END_DT, A.NRX_CNT, A.NRX_CNT - B.NRX_CNT as DELTA
FROM lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary A
INNER JOIN
lnd_wkly_plan_rx_summary B
ON A.JoinableField=B.JoinableField